# Should I do online transaction [WannaCry Ramsomeware]

Tags: wannacrypt, ransomware

Can I do online transaction safely without getting affected by WannaCry Ramsomeware? If I do, then how would I be affected?

The site I'm trying is **Amazon**.

Comment: I'm confused why you removed the WannaCrypt tag. WannaCrypt is another name for the WannaCry virus.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I got an edit suggestion...anyways I added it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no relation between you doing online transactions and Wannacry infections.

Wannacry spreads through file shares, not via the browser.

[How do malware like WannaCry infect new computers even if someone on those computers does not click a link or visit a website?](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/6ayrov/eli5_how_do_malware_like_wannacry_infect_new/) (Reddit)

Answer (score 0):

*Wannacry* affects PC by clicking on email links from unknown sender with *wannacry* virus. I think if you open only the trusted emails then you are safe to do anything in your PC. In your case its online transaction. They don't want your Rupees or Dollar but Bitcoins for release your locked files in your PC. so I think there is no impact on online transactions.

Comment: This answer is very incomplete. Most infections occur from scanning port 445 once infected, **not** from users clicking emails. Maybe only some initials ones.

Comment: It starts by opening an attachment in an email, it spreads through port 445 if unpatched.

Comment: "Wannacry affects PC by clicking on email links" - It also is a worm.  So it means you could do nothing and still be affected if you don't patch your system.